# How to avoid manual editing of manifest file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, activex, manifest, regfreecom

My VB.Net application uses isolated activeX (outer), that depends on another activeX (inner), both are using registration-free-com.

The generated manifest file contains only the information for the outer activeX. (probably because vs cannot know that the outer activeX is using inner activeX )

When I re-build my project, I always need to manually add the information for the inner activeX to the manifest file, otherwise the application only shows the outer, without the inner.

Is there a way to inform visual studio (2010) that I do not want it to re-generate the manifest file for each build?

Thanks,

Atara

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
[/MANIFEST (Create Side-by-Side Assembly Manifest)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2c0w594%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I have VB.Net application (I added it now to the original question).
Do I have such a flag also in VB .Net projects?
[I did not find the "Configuration" nor "Linker" nodes in my projectProperties window]